# LXDE - bring window to the front

Tags: linux

How can I programmatically bring a window on top of the others? I'm using a full screen app and I need to bring a second window temporary on the front.

Comment: Did you event read the Title? -> LXDE and the Tag "Linux"?

Comment: You should not. Leave such policies to the window manager

Answer (score 6):

I use `wmctrl` for that:

```
wmctrl -a "window name"
```

Or, if you know the PID of the application

```
wmctrl -i -a "$PID"
```

Comment: Thanks choroba, I would like to add that with `wmctrl -l` you can list the  windows  being  managed  by  the window manager and the window name is in the column 4 (with spaces).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Openbox#Windows_load_behind_the_active_window),

> **Windows load behind the active window**
>
> Some application windows (such as Firefox windows) may load behind the
>   currently active window, causing you to need to switch to the window
>   you just created to focus it. To fix this behavior add this to your
>   `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml` file, inbetween the `<openbox_config>` and
>   `</openbox_config>` tags:
>
> ```
> <applications>
>   <application class="*">
>     <focus>yes</focus>
>   </application>
> </applications>
> ```

In Debian Strech 9 LXDE, the config is in `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml`.  You'll need to edit this file as root.  The `<applications>` tags already exist at the end of the file and, in my case, there are bunch of helpful comments which explain things.  As they pertain to your situation,

> ```
>   <application name="first element of window's WM_CLASS property (see xprop)"
>               class="second element of window's WM_CLASS property (see xprop)"
>                role="the window's WM_WINDOW_ROLE property (see xprop)">
>   # the name or the class can be set, or both. this is used to match
>   # windows when they appear. role can optionally be set as well, to
>   # further restrict your matches.
>
>   # the name, class, and role use simple wildcard matching such as those
>   # used by a shell. you can use * to match any characters and ? to match
>   # any single character.
> ```

`xprop` is a "property displayer for X".  To read more about it, type `man xprop`.  Basically, setting class equal to the wildcard `*` says, "Apply the inner options to all new applications".  The inner option is then `<focus>yes</focus>` which means put the new application in front of all the current windows.

Once you've added those lines, make sure you run

`openbox --reconfigure`

That will apply your updates.  As always, you can read more about what that command does with `man openbox`.